# Extract & repack system.img for Nexus 5 lolipop

Tags: rom-flashing, images, system

I'm following [this link](http://muzso.hu/2012/08/10/how-to-pack-and-unpack-system.img-and-userdata.img-from-an-android-factory-image) to extract; make some changes & then repack `system.img` which is present in nexus 5 image. (Version Tag android-5.1.1_r9)

The guide works for 4.1.1, but not for 5.1.1_r9.

Because, there is no *sparse_crc32.c* & *simg2img.c* present in ext4_utils folder.

So how can I extract & repack the img file.

**P.S.** - I dont know much about gcc.

Please help.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Those files have been moved to another location:

check folder libsparse/ in the following repo 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/

I have checked it with 6.0.1 image, and it works.